# using closure in custom session function

Tags: php, session, closures

I am trying to write a custom SESSION class for PHP to move sessions into the database and away from the file system.
An error is thrown only in the `_read()` method when the closure `$connect2DB` is being called. In all other methods calling `$connect2DB` does not cause any errors.
Also if I instantiate the class as an object myself all methods including the infamous `_read()` works as expected. Can you find the error?

I have following code:

```
class sessionDBHandler {
    public function __construct() {
        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, "_open"),
            array($this, "_close"),
            array($this, "_read"),
            array($this, "_write"),
            array($this, "_destroy"),
            array($this, "_gc")
        );
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }

    public function _open() {
        global $sessCon;
        global $HOST;
        global $USER;
        global $PW;
        global $DATABASE;

        $sessCon=new mysqli($HOST,$USER,$PW,$DATABASE); //mysqli connection
    }

    public function _close() {
        global $sessCon;

        $sessCon->close();
    }

    public function _read($id) {
        global $sessCon;
        global $connect2DB;
        global $SESSIONTAB;

        $qRes=$connect2DB($sessCon,'select `data` from `'.$SESSIONTAB.'` where `ID`=?',array("s",$id)); //<-- error message here

        if(!empty($qRes["res"][0]["data"])) return $qRes["res"][0]["data"];
        else return '';
    }

    public function _write($id,$data) {
        global $sessCon;
        global $connect2DB;
        global $SESSIONTAB;

        $qRes=$connect2DB($sessCon,'select `ID` from `'.$SESSIONTAB.'` where `ID`=?',array("s",$id));

        $param=array(); //buliding SQL query parameters
        $param[0]="sis";
        $param[]=$id;
        $param[]=time();
        $param[]=$data;
        if(!empty($qRes["res"][0]["ID"])) {
            $param[0].="s";
            $param[]=$id;
        }

        $qRes=$connect2DB($sessCon,(!empty($qRes["res"][0]["ID"]) ? 'update' : 'insert').' `'.$SESSIONTAB.'` set `ID`=?, `access`=?, `data`=?'.(!empty($qRes["res"][0]["ID"]) ? ' where `ID`=?' : ''),$param);

        if($qRes["info"]["affectedRows"]>0) return true;
        else return '';
    }

    public function _destroy($id) {
        global $sessCon;
        global $connect2DB;
        global $SESSIONTAB;

        $qRes=$connect2DB($sessCon,'delete from `'.$SESSIONTAB.'` where `ID`=?',array("s",$id));

        if($qRes["info"]["affectedRows"]>0) return true;
        else return '';
    }

    public function _gc($max) {
        global $sessCon;
        global $connect2DB;
        global $SESSIONTAB;

        $qRes=$connect2DB($sessCon,'delete from `'.$SESSIONTAB.'` where `access`<?',array("i",(time()-$max)));

        if($qRes["info"]["affectedRows"]>0) return true;
        else return '';
    }
}
```

and I tell PHP where it findes those functions (before calling `session_start()` here:

```
new sessionDBHandler();
```

My problem seems to be the closure I am using as my MySQL abstraction layer. The error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /Users/user/Sites/script.php on line 401
```

which suggests to me that it somehow cannot find the namespace of $connect2DB.
The thing is though if I call those functions without __constructor and its `session_set_save_handler` directive, it will work just fine:

```
$test=new sessionDBHandler();
$test->_open();
echo $test->_read("d6e08112ff6fc8a7eb6e76832327bf81");
$test->_close();
```

the above works without an error.
Now I am using closures here because I have to keep the footprint of this script very low and unset $connect2DB at the bottom of the script among other reasons so I would love to keep the current abstraction layer.

Any ideas what I can do here?

thanks everyone!

perhaps the $connect2DB is not initialized when sessions is being called?

#### connnect2DB

```
/**
* Simple MySQLi abstraction layer
*
* @param resource $mysqli The MySQLi connection link
* @param string   $query  The MySQL query for prepaired statement
* @param array    $v      The parameters to replace ? in $query. First element must be the type
* @param integer  $o      Option for more debug infos [0]=no infos(default) [1]=adding debug infos
*
* @return array [for select]=associative array of table result  [for everything else]=associative array with affectedRows,info and insertID
*
* @author Dominik Wilkowski
*/
$connect2DB=function($mysqli,$query,$v=array(),$o=0) {

    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        return array('info'=>array('error'=>'Connect failed: '.$mysqli->connect_error)); //error handling here
        exit();
    }

    if($v && (substr_count($query,"?")!=strlen($v[0]) || strlen($v[0])!=((count($v)-1)>=0 ? (count($v)-1) : 0))) {
        return array('info'=>array('error'=>'Placeholders are unequal! placeholders:'.substr_count($query,"?").', replacements:'.strlen($v[0]).', param:'.(count($v)-1).' ('.$v[0].')')); //error handling here...
        exit();
    }

    if($res=$mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            //dynamically bind all $v
            if($v) {
            $values=array($v[0]);
            for($i=1; $i<count($v); $i++) {
                ${'bind'.$i}=$v[$i];
                $values[]=&${'bind'.$i};
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($res,'bind_param'),$values);
        }
        $res->execute();

        //bind all table rows to result
        if(strtolower(substr($query,0,6))=="select") {
            $field=$fields=$tempRow=array();
            $meta=$res->result_metadata();
            while($field=$meta->fetch_field()) {
                $fieldName=$field->name;
                $fields[]=&$tempRow[$fieldName];
            }
            $meta->free_result();
            call_user_func_array(array($res,"bind_result"),$fields);

            //return associative array
            $results=array();
            $i=0;
            while($res->fetch()) {
                $results["res"][$i]=array();
                foreach($tempRow as $k=>$v2) $results["res"][$i][$k] = $v2;
                $i++;
            }
            $res->free_result();

        }
        else { //return infos about the query

            if($mysqli->warning_count) {
                if($err=$mysqli->query("SHOW WARNINGS")) {
                    $row=$err->fetch_row();
                    $results["info"]["error"].=$row[0].' ('.$row[1].'): '.$row[2];
                    $err->close();
                }
            }
            $results["info"]["affectedRows"]=$mysqli->affected_rows;
            $results["info"]["info"]=$mysqli->info;
            $results["info"]["insertID"]=$mysqli->insert_id;
        }

        $res->close();
    }

    if($o===1) { //adding debug infos
        $q=$query;
        for($i=1;$i<count($v);$i++) $q=preg_replace("/\?/",(substr($v[0],($i-1),1)=="s" ? '"' : '').$v[$i].(substr($v[0],($i-1),1)=="s" ? '"' : ''),$q,1);
        $results["info"]["query"]=$q;
        $results["info"]["param"]=json_encode($v);
    }

    if(strtolower(substr($query,0,6))=="update" || strtolower(substr($query,0,6))=="delete") { //optimize at update and delete
        preg_match_all('/((update|delete) `(.*)` )/i',$query,$tables);
        foreach($tables[3] as $t) $mysqli->query('OPTIMIZE TABLE '.$t);
    }

    return $results;
};
```

## Update #2

Our earlier test suggested that namespace indeed does not seem to be initialized at the time when `_read()` runs so I wrote a small test case for this to double check.

```
<?php
$LOGIN='login credentials';

//Closure
$nob=function() {
    return 'closure running!<br>';
};

//Session handler
class sessionDBHandler {
    public function __construct() {
        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, "_open"),
            array($this, "_close"),
            array($this, "_read"),
            array($this, "_write"),
            array($this, "_destroy"),
            array($this, "_gc")
        );
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }

    public function _open() {
        global $sessCon;
        global $LOGIN;

        echo '_open running with: '.$LOGIN.'<br>';
        $sessCon='connection established!<br>';
    }

    public function _close() {
        global $sessCon;

        echo $sessCon='connection closed!<br>';
    }

    public function _read($id) {
        global $sessCon;
        global $nob;

        echo $nob();
        echo 'requested id is: '.$id.'<br>';
        echo 'sessCon is: '.$sessCon;
    }

    public function _write($id,$data) {
        global $sessCon;

        echo 'requested id is: '.$id.' and data: '.$data.'<br>';
        echo 'sessCon is: '.$sessCon;
    }

    public function _destroy($id) {
        global $sessCon;

        echo 'requested id is: '.$id.'<br>';
        echo 'sessCon is: '.$sessCon;
    }

    public function _gc($max) {
        global $sessCon;

        echo 'requested max is: '.$max.'<br>';
        echo 'sessCon is: '.$sessCon;
    }
}

new sessionDBHandler();
session_start();
?>
```

Interestingly enough this will run without errors and output this:

```
_open running with: login credentials
closure running!
requested id is: 746b70a979d9ef8c6686e659707b4b38
sessCon is: connection established!
requested id is: 746b70a979d9ef8c6686e659707b4b38 and data:
sessCon is: connection established!
connection closed!
```

Now that suggests that there seems to be an error in my particular implementation. Whoever wants to have a stab at this is very welcome to join :)

## Update #3

I want to unset my closure after I run my application and had therefore `unset($connect2DB);` on the very bottom of the script. This however seemed to have caused a "premature" unset somehow. Removing this will remove the error.

#### However

Is there a way to safely unset my closure after the script has run so it doesn't flow into the main script?

Comment: I don't see any assignment to `$connect2DB`.

Comment: what do you mean? do you want me to post connect2DB?

Comment: You're using a variable, so somewhere there has to be an assignment to that variable. That's different from the function definition.

Comment: ok I don't know what that would look like and think that this sounds like the solution :) currently I am doing this: `$connect2DB=function($mysqli,$query,$v=array(),$o=0) { ... }`

Comment: That's what I wanted to see. I think that should work. Which is line 401?

Comment: I added the line into the code. It is in _lockoutRead first call of connect2DB. thanks for looking into this.

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($connect2DB)` at that location?

Comment: well nothing as the script aborts right there and above the first $connect2DB is no $qRes... :)

Comment: The issue is with the value of `$connect2DB`, we need to see if it's not getting the value you expect. It would help if you posted the part of the script that sets it.

Comment: well keep in mind that everything works if I call it without `session_set_save_handler()`... But I can post it too. I just think it will make things more complicated :)

Comment: I wonder why you're calling it through a variable and not just defining it as an ordinary function.

Comment: yeah as I said in the question (that has admittedly gotten pretty big) I have to keep the footprint as low as possible for this script and as far as I know there is no way to unset functions... If we can't find the fix then I guess I have to just live with it?!

Comment: I changed from closure to function and that fixed the error BUT I still have the closure in all other methods and they work suggesting that only the _read method does not see $connect2DB?! That now seems very strange to me?! Any Ideas?

Comment: Not directly related to the question at hand, but if you need database abstraction, use an object-oriented solution such as PDO. It's seldom ever a good idea to roll your own.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks but this has been working for ages now in a bunch of very different environments and I am pretty happy with it. Never had a problem :) (also PDO is too slow for what we are doing here)

Comment: Dominik, (annoying question) ... Should this question really be tagged [closures] given that we are talking about PHP's use of the term, which does not conform with the tag definition?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I am happy to call it whatever and change the tag but this question is directly directed at as to why the closure cannot be called... everything works without the closure so my take is that the namespace of the closure is somehow initialized AFTER the session methods... wouldn't that be interesting for closure questions?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Sounds like it might be an interesting topic of discussion on meta, except PHP uses a *lot* of terms that do not conform to their usual definitions.

Comment: Mmm Meta ... discussion could go either way ... (a) rambles on for a long time, or (b) gets closed immediately. Never can tell in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is some kind of order-dependency -- either `_read()` is being called before you initialize `$connect2DB` or after you clear it.

Comment: @Barmar yes I think so too but is there something I can do? eg can I initialize connect2DB from within _read? point to it or anything that does not require me to use a function?

Comment: Write a simple noop function and point it to that.

Comment: can you supply an example? I'll google it in the meantime ;)

Comment: I'm following this interesting discussion and think Barmar means you might define a dummy "closure", `$noop = ...;`, in the same scope as `$connect2DB`, then call it from  `_read()` (remember the `global` statement). If calling `$noop()` does not generate an error and `$connect2DB` does generate an error, then that's evidence that `$connect2DB` gets destroyed.

Comment: right. unfortunately I get the same result: `$nob=function() {
 return '##';
};` and then calling it in `_read()` with `global $nob;

  echo $nob();` results in `Fatal error: Function name must be a string`

Comment: OK but you've learned something. Nothing can be destroying `$nob` so it's highly likely that it's not been created when `_read()` is called.

Comment: I tried to put it into the __constructor but cannot think of a method to like "force-reference" the closure there...